# LQP answer, what to do when the right thing is code made in a comment?

Tags: discussion

I'm learning to review this queue. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16202103) the answer I was shown. The comment is helpful, maybe even good. I tried to edit the answer but felt I need the person answering to actually add the code.

What's the proper thing to do? Given the options, I chose "delete" - after adding a comment to turn the comment (again, by the person answering) into code in the answer.

Wish there was a better option.

Comment: That answer isn't worthy of a delete vote. It's not a comment either; it's actually answering the question. Yes, it can be improved upon; but that's what voting is for.

Answer (score 1):

Rob's comment is correct. This doesn't even slightly qualify as "not an answer" or "very low quality" (not that VLQ is actually a particularly helpful consideration; it almost never comes up). Not only does it give some general explanation and a suggested course of action, it's even plausibly linked to the actual question and contains more than enough details to get started without much further work. That is, it's *an* answer, and also an answer to *that* question.

You can try editing; otherwise, leave a comment and choose <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>. Trying to *delete* this is thoroughly incorrect. I'm not convinced even downvoting is appropriate, but I don't know the tech very well.